# C# LINQ TO XML - Remove "[]" characters from the DTD header

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

I recently created a small C# windows forms/LINQ to XML app in VS2010 that does exactly what it's supposed to do, except for one thing: it adds "[]" to the end of the DOCTYPE tag, which apparently is causing files to be rejected from a legacy system. Here's a before and after:

Before

```
<!DOCTYPE ichicsr SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/xml/icsr-xml-v2.1.dtd">
```

After

```
<!DOCTYPE ichicsr SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/xml/icsr-xml-v2.1.dtd"[]>
```

These characters get added after the file is saved within the program using the .Save function. The program allows selection of an .xml file, then "cleans" it by removing certain tags, then saves it. When the process begins, the files do not have the "[]" in the DOCTYPE. After saving, they do. Does LINQ to XML add these?

Is there any way to keep the program from adding these characters?

Comment: It's very unlikely that Linq would add anything automatically. Why don't you put together a small example of the problem and post it here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Evidently, when `XDocument` parses an XML document that contains a Document Type Declaration, an empty "internal subset" is automatically inserted if one doesn't exist. (The internal subset is the part surrounded by `[]` in the `<!DOCTYPE>`).

The result is well-formed XML. However, if your legacy system can't handle it, you can remove the internal subset from the DTD by setting the [`XDocumentType.InternalSubset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype.internalsubset) property to `null`:

```
XDocument document = ...;
if (document.DocumentType != null)
    document.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null;
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done it. So far it's passing every test.

Comment: Note this doesn't currently work in Mono (`2.10.9`), as you can't assign null to `InternalSubset`, though you *can* specify null when you're creating a new `XDocumentType`. When parsing/saving an `Info.plist`, this leads to a catch-22: outputting `[]` in the file will cause compilation to fail in MonoTouch. Loading `Info.plist` with an empty internal subset causes `[]` to be emitted, and you can't set the `.InternalSubset = null`. And `XDocument.DocumentType` is read-only. Woe is me!

Comment: I hit the same thing (using mono on mac to modify an Info.plist). I found a decent workaround using XmlDocument to modify the DOCTYPE after you are done doing your work with XDocument, and I posted it below. Until I found it I was about to do some awful string replacement or resort to - shudder - XmlReader/XmlWriter.

Comment: `InternalSubset` is `null` but some XmlWriter (`XDocument.Save(Response.Output)`) still outputs `[]`. Can't really figure it out.

Comment: @AlexKamburov: Post a new question with your code, and include the version of .NET you're targeting.

Answer (score 12):

If you are dealing with this on Mono (like cod3monk3y) for cases like modifying Info.plist, you can use the old XmlDocument class to fix things up after you use XDocument to create/modify your xml file.

The code assumes your "Info.plist" file is located at the path infoPlist:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xDocument = XDocument.Load (infoPlist);
// Do your manipulations here
xDocument.Save (infoPlist);
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load (infoPlist);
if (xmlDocument.DocumentType != null)
{
    var name = xmlDocument.DocumentType.Name;
    var publicId = xmlDocument.DocumentType.PublicId;
    var systemId = xmlDocument.DocumentType.SystemId;
    var parent = xmlDocument.DocumentType.ParentNode;
    var documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset = xmlDocument.CreateDocumentType(name, publicId, systemId, null);
    parent.ReplaceChild(documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset, xmlDocument.DocumentType);
}
xmlDocument.Save (infoPlist);
```