# XDocument.Load() introduces empty InternalSubset in the DTD header

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Given the input:

```
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd">
<cXML />
```

My code returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd"[]>
<cXML />
```

The empty InternalSubset (`[]`) that was introduced bugged me so I tried to find where the problem stems from. It turns out that `XDocument.Load()` is the culprit where the following is executed:

```
case XmlNodeType.DocumentType: 
  c.AddNodeSkipNotify(new XDocumentType(r.LocalName, r.GetAttribute("PUBLIC"), r.GetAttribute("SYSTEM"), r.Value, r.DtdInfo));
```

`r.Value` is an empty string instead of `null` so XDocument.DocumentType.InternalSubset is an empty string instead of `null`.

Here is the sample code:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", Encoding.UTF8.WebName.ToUpper(), string.Empty),
                new XDocumentType("cXML", null, "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd", null),
                new XElement("cXML"));

TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(writer);
doc.Dump();
doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(writer.ToString()));
doc.Dump();
```

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** [Remove empty square bracket characters from the DTD header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12358061/1497596)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem when called after `Load()`:

```
if (doc.DocumentType != null && doc.DocumentType.InternalSubset == string.Empty)
{
   doc.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null;
}
```