# Wrong [ ] at the end of xmldocument type

Tags: .net, f#, plist, xmldocument

Hi I'm updating a plist using XmlDocument and when I save it looks like this `<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd" []>`

intend of `<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">`

this is my code

UpdatePlist.fs:

```
namespace TestPlist

open System
open System.Xml


module UpdatePlist =
  type PlistLocation = PlistLocation of string
  type Version = Version of string

  let updatePlist ( PlistLocation(plist), Version(stable), Version(revision), Version(last) )  =
    let mydocument = new XmlDocument()
    mydocument.Load(plist)
    mydocument.PreserveWhitespace |> ignore
    let PlistNodes = mydocument.SelectNodes("descendant::key")
    let version = stable + "." + revision + "." + last
    PlistNodes.Item(8).NextSibling.InnerText <- version
    mydocument.Save(plist)
    "done"
```

and Program.fs:

```
 namespace TestPlist
 open UpdatePlist
 module Main=
   [<EntryPoint>]
   let main argv = 
       updatePlist(PlistLocation("../../Info.plist"), Version("8"), Version("5"), Version("9"))
       |> printfn "%A"
```

And the Plist File Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
   <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
   <array>
     <integer>1</integer>
     <integer>2</integer>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
   <string>6.0</string>
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>
   </string>
   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
   <array>
     <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
   </array>
   <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
   <string>
   </string>
   <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>8</string>
   <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
   <string></string>
   <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
   <string></string>
   <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
   <string>8.5.9</string>
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>1</string>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Please Help!

Comment: please fix your code then maybe we can help

Comment: fix it, Thanks @Carsten

Comment: My guess is that you're not getting any help with your question because you're giving us no way to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Hi @MarkSeemann, I have updated the code, and added a plist file

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
let documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset = mydocument.CreateDocumentType("plist", "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN", "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd", null);
mydocument.ReplaceChild(documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset, mydocument.DocumentType) |> ignore
```

all before save()

I found this thread, 
[C# LINQ TO XML - Remove "[]" characters from the DTD header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358061/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-remove-characters-from-the-dtd-header)
so this question already exist before :/ sorry